# Data from multiple workbooks into one master. mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder called Diesel in my C:, with a zmaster file and multiple files that contain data.

The zmaster contains only headers from A1 to P3. Meaning I would start pasting data from A4 onwards. My data files contain multiple rows.

When I run the following code iget a type 13 error, type mismatch:

```js
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "C:\Diesel\"

Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination = Worksheets("Concentrado").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

Filename = Dir

Loop



End Sub
```

I get the error on the ActiveSheet.Paste line

I don't know what Im getting wrong.

Comment: `Destination :=`

Answer (score 1):

you need to  add : on this code
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination

this should be

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination: =

or else it will not determine or see the file which  it should be paste.